# Counter loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, methods, counter

I have created a game where the player collects pods on the game board. I need to make an evasive maneuver so that after five turns when the player is one space away from the pod, the pod will transport 10 spaces away from the player. I believe my counter is not working and that is why the evasive maneuver is not working.

```
public class Pod {


    int podPositionX;
    int podPositionY;
    String podDirection;
    int layoutWidth; 
    int layoutHeight;
    boolean podVisable = true; 
    int playerX; 
    int playerY;
    int count = 0;

    public Pod(int x, int y, String direction, int width, int height){

        podPositionX = x;
        podPositionY = y;
        podDirection = direction;
        layoutWidth = width; 
        layoutHeight = height;
        count=count+1;

    }   


    //Inspector Methods?
    // Will get the the pods positon and will return it
    public int getX()
    {
             return podPositionX;
    }

    //This method returns the current Y coordinate of the pod.
    public int getY() 
    {
        return podPositionY;
    }


    //This method returns true if the pod is visible, false otherwise. Once the 
    //pod has been caught, it should always return false.
    public boolean isVisible(){

        if (playerX == podPositionX && playerY == podPositionY && podVisable == true){
            podVisable = false;}
        return podVisable; 

    }


    // to move pod diagonally across screen//

    public void move(){
        //Calling invasive methods!!
        while  (count>5 && count < 100){
        podPositionX=transportX();
        podPositionY=transportY();
        }

        /****************** To make pod move **************/
        if (podDirection.equals("NW")|| podDirection.equals("NE")){
            podPositionY = podPositionY + 1;}

        if (podDirection.equals("SW")|| podDirection.equals("SE")){ 
            podPositionY = podPositionY-1;}

        if (podDirection.equals("NE")|| podDirection.equals("SE")){
            podPositionX = podPositionX+1;}

        if(podDirection.equals("NW")|| podDirection.equals("SW")){
           podPositionX = podPositionX-1;}

        /****************To make Pod bounce off wall******************/

        //make pod bounce off left wall
        if (podPositionX <= 1){
            if (podDirection.equals("SW")){
                podDirection = "SE";}

            if (podDirection.equals("NW")){
                podDirection = "NE";}
        }
        //make pod bounce off top
        if (podPositionY >= layoutHeight-1){
            if (podDirection.equals("NW")){
                podDirection = "SW";}

            if (podDirection.equals("NE")){
                podDirection = "SE";}
        }

        //make pod bounce off right wall
        if (podPositionX >= layoutWidth-1){
            if (podDirection.equals("NE")){
                podDirection = "NW";}

            if (podDirection.equals("SE" )){
                podDirection = "SW";}
        }

        //make pod bounce off bottom wall
        if (podPositionY <= 1){

            if (podDirection.equals("SW")){
                podDirection = "NW";}

            if (podDirection.equals("SE")){
                podDirection = "NE";}
            }

        }



    // to get player x and y positions
    public void playerAt(int x, int y){

        playerX = x; 
        playerY = y;




}
    //envasive maneuver so that after 5 turns the pod can be transported away from the player if it is 1 spot away from the player.
    //then the count is set to 100 so it will exit the loop and not be able to transport the pod again. 
    public int transportX(){


            if (podPositionX == playerX -1 || podPositionX == playerX +1){
                podPositionX= playerX +10;
                count = 100;}

            return podPositionX;
    }
    public int transportY(){
        if  (podPositionY == playerY -1 || podPositionY == playerY +1){
                podPositionY= playerY +10;
                count=100;}
        return podPositionY;
    }

}
```

the code my teacher provided us. Can no be touched so i can not put a counter in this file.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Project1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    // Member variables for visual objects.
    private JLabel[][] board; // 2D array of labels. Displays either # for player,
                              // * for pod, or empty space
    private JButton northButton, // player presses to move up
                    southButton, // player presses to move down
                    eastButton,  // player presses to move right
                    westButton;  // player presses to move left

    // Current width and height of board (will make static later).
    private int width = 15;
    private int height = 9;

    // Current location of player
    private int playerX = 7;
    private int playerY = 4;

    // Pod object stored in array for efficiency
    private Pod[] pods;
    int podCount = 4;

    public Project1() {

        // Construct a panel to put the board on and another for the buttons
        JPanel boardPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(height, width));
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4));

        // Use a loop to construct the array of labels, adding each to the
        // board panel as it is constructed. Note that we create this in
        // "row major" fashion by making the y-coordinate the major 
        // coordinate. We also make sure that increasing y means going "up"
        // by building the rows in revers order.
        board = new JLabel[height][width];
        for (int y = height-1; y >= 0; y--) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {

                // Construct a label to represent the tile at (x, y)
                board[y][x] = new JLabel(" ", JLabel.CENTER);

                // Add it to the 2D array of labels representing the visible board
                boardPanel.add(board[y][x]);
            }
        }

        // Construct the buttons, register to listen for their events,
        // and add them to the button panel
        northButton = new JButton("N");
        southButton = new JButton("S");
        eastButton = new JButton("E");
        westButton = new JButton("W");

        // Listen for events on each button
        northButton.addActionListener(this);
        southButton.addActionListener(this);
        eastButton.addActionListener(this);
        westButton.addActionListener(this);

        // Add each to the panel of buttons
        buttonPanel.add(northButton); 
        buttonPanel.add(southButton); 
        buttonPanel.add(eastButton); 
        buttonPanel.add(westButton);

        // Add everything to a main panel attached to the content pane
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Size the app and make it visible
        setSize(300, 200);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Auxiliary method to create game setup
        createGame();
    }

    // Auxiliary method used to create board. Sets player, treasure, and walls.
    public void createGame() {

        // Construct array of Pod objects
        pods = new Pod[podCount];

        // Construct each Pod in the array, passing it its initial location,
        // direction of movement, and the width and heigh of board. This will
        // later be modified to be done at random.
        pods[0] = new Pod(1, 5, "NE", width, height);
        pods[1] = new Pod(2, 1, "SW", width, height);
        pods[2] = new Pod(12, 2, "NW", width, height);
        pods[3] = new Pod(13, 6, "SE", width, height);

        // Call method to draw board
        drawBoard();

    }

    // Auxiliary method to display player and pods in labels.
    public void drawBoard() {

        // "Erase" previous board by writing " " in each label
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                board[y][x].setText(" ");
            }
        }

        // Get location of each pod and write * into that label. We only
        // do this for pods not yet caught.
        for (int p = 0; p < podCount; p++) {
            if (pods[p].isVisible()) {
                board[pods[p].getY()][pods[p].getX()].setText("*");
            }
        }

        // Write the player onto the board.
        board[playerY][playerX].setText("#");
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // Determine which button was pressed, and move player in that
        // direction (making sure they don't leave the board).
        if (e.getSource() == southButton && playerY > 0) {
            playerY--;
        }
        if (e.getSource() == northButton && playerY < height-1) {
            playerY++;
        }
        if (e.getSource() == eastButton && playerX < width-1) {
            playerX++;
        }
        if (e.getSource() == westButton && playerX > 0) {
            playerX--;
        }

        // Move the pods and notify the pods about player location.        
        for (int p = 0; p < podCount; p++) {
            pods[p].move();
            pods[p].playerAt(playerX, playerY);
        }

        // Redraw the board
        drawBoard();

    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Project1 a = new Project1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you debug your code ?

Comment: @AngelaRucci What is your question?

Comment: Initially your `count` is 1. And the only place that modifies the value are the `transport` methods. But the condition in `while (count > 5 && count < 100) { transportXY }` will never be `true` for count 1 and so the transport methods never executed. Did you forget to increment it somewhere or are the transport methods in the wrong place?

Comment: my idea that every time the pod would move it would increment the count by one

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at this quickly now. You said the problem is with the count variable. I see that you are incrementing it in the constructor i.e

```
public Pod(int, int, String, int, int){
count = count + 1;
}
```

why not put it in the move method. That way every time the move method is used the count variable will be incremented by one.

```
public void move(){
this.count++;
}
```

Also it is very hard to see exactly what you think your code is doing. I tried to run it and nothing happens. Sometimes it is good to print something to the console.